# Error in validating minimum length for text field

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, form-validation

I have used the below

`<input type="text" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-number  validate-length minimum-length-4 maximum-length-8" title="Purchase Order" name="custom1" id="custom1">`

For validating length the **maximum-length-8** works. 
But **minimum-length-4** not working.
Somebody please let me know if you have any solution

Comment: this seems correct, can you share a link OR full form's HTML that contains this element  ?

Comment: Did you able to find any solution for this issue? if so can you please update here.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="custom1" name="custom1" title="Purchase Order" class="input-text required-entry validate-length maximum-length-8 minimum-length-4 validate-digits">
```

Comment: when using validate-digits also its not working